# looking for a slowly varing function with given properties

Tags: real-analysis, probability

I am looking for a slowly varying function $L(.)$ such that the function $f(s)=s+(1-s)^2L\left( \frac{1}{1-s}\right)$ is a probability generating function with $f'(1)=1$ and $f''(1)=\infty$.
I tryed $L(x)=\ln(x)$ but in this case $f(s)$ was not probability generating function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider any convenient probability generating function $f(s)$ satisfying $f'(1)=1$ and $f''(1)=\infty$.

Define the function : $$\boxed{L(x)=x^2f\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)+x(1-x)}$$

This function satisfies $\quad f(s)=s+(1-s)^2L\left( \frac{1}{1-s}\right)\quad$ because :

with $\quad x=\frac{1}{1-s} \quad\implies\quad \frac{x-1}{x}=s$

$L\left(\frac{1}{1-s}\right)=\left(\frac{1}{1-s}\right)^2f\left(s\right)+\left(\frac{1}{1-s}\right)\left(1-\left(\frac{1}{1-s}\right)\right)$

$(1-s)^2L\left(\frac{1}{1-s}\right)=f\left(s\right)-s$

$f(s)=s+(1-s)^2L\left( \frac{1}{1-s}\right)$

With this method you can find as many functions $L(x)$ as you want.

COMMENT about the expected "slowly varying $L(x)$ function".

$L(x)$ and $f(s)$ are related functions through the specified equation $f(s)=s+(1-s)^2L\left( \frac{1}{1-s}\right)$ or inversely $L(x)=x^2f\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)+x(1-x)$ .

Insofar $f(s)$ is a given function there is no choice for $L(x)$ to exactly satisfy $f(s)=s+(1-s)^2L\left( \frac{1}{1-s}\right)$. This defines the function $L(x)$ and you can't expect that $L(x)$ be smooth or not. You have to accept the function $L(x)$ as this function is given by  $L(x)=x^2f\left(\frac{x-1}{x}\right)+x(1-x)$.

May be the wording of question has to be differently written in order to obtain what you are expecting. Of course if the question becomes different the answer would be different.

Comment: Nice and so simple ....(after reading the solution). Cheers :-)

Comment: I think that the function $L(.)$ given in the answer is not slowly varying.

Comment: Slowly varying is something else. This depends of the choice of functions $f(s)$. No definitive answer can be given on this point. Try with some functions $f(s)$ and see what happen.

Comment: The condition that $L(.)$ has to be slowly varying is given in the problem.

Comment: See the comment added to my main answer.

Comment: I am not native English, but I think that in the question it is not saying that $f(,)$ is given. I am looking for a slowly varying function $L(.)$ such that $s+(1-s)^2L(\frac{1}{1-s})$ is a probability generating function with some properties.

Comment: If I well understand now you are looking for a couple of associated functions $f(s)$ and $L(x)$ with given specific conditions. That was not what I supposed first. So the problem remains open. Sorry for my not well appropriate answer.